# How to Enable OS-login on GSuite Group Level

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on to enable OS-login and I want to know if there is a way to enable OS-login(by applying oslogin roles) on GSuite group level, instead of for each individual user, so that I can manage users' accesses a lot easier.

What about grant user sudo at GSuite group level too?

Wondering if anyone out there has any experience with those.

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: You can use OS login API if you are an [Organization Admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9197205?hl=en) to manage the resource creation. However, OS login will not enable you to run such commands as sudo as per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/#benefits_of_os_login). You can also look at this document how you can assign [OS login roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#grant-iam-roles).

Comment: I have GCP resources OSlogin enabled(project,or instance level). I can enable user to use oslogin by give them oslogin roles.I can also enable use "sudo" by adding user to the google-sudoers group,they all work.But enable oslogin role & add user to the google-sudoers group are @ user level. What I want to know is that since Gsuite has groups that gather users, can I apply oslogin roles at group level not user level so that managing users will be easier like add/delete, i just need to touch the group and not all the resources that the user has access or need access. Same for sudo.

Comment: There are two os login roles, OSlogin.admin and OSlogin.user. admin gives users sudoers access, user does not. would that solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have not tested the osligin admin role yet, but if it gives user sudo, then I don't have to worry about the sudo part. But I still want to know if I can grant the osligin role, or/and oslogin admin role at group level instead of indivisual user level.

Comment: Yeah, you can add Gsuite groups in IAM and then add either of the roles to them. I don't think you should experience any issues with that.